# How to limit the Design surface area of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, visual-studio-designer

I have inherited forms in C# WinForms.

I would like to limit the design surface area on the derived forms, so they can only add controls to a designated panel/area and no more.

How can I limit the designer in this way? Thanks!

Comment: Cannot understand what you mean at all.

Comment: What he means is if you inherit a form, the base form elements will appear in the designer. He wants to limit the area that changes are allowed in the derived form.